# What is the word for a surrounding sequence?

Tags: single-word-requests

A pattern that begins a word is generally denoted as "prefix",
one that ends a word is generally denoted as "suffix".

Is there a word that indicates a pattern that surrounds a word. For instance (hello), is there a word that indicates the parentheses?

So if I have several patterns i.e.:

"hello"
(hello)
{hello}
[hello]

etc. What word do I use for the surrounding pattern?

Comment: Please edit question and specify a context: grammar, linguistics, computer science, other.  (Otherwise, assertion about "generally denoted" is false.)

Comment: You don't agree that prefix and suffix generally denote patterns that begin and end words?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three more -fix words you may be looking for:

1. The generic term for things attaching to words is *[affix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix)*
2. The term for something inserted into a word, as in *abso-fucking-lutely* is *[infix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix)*
3. What you are looking for is something attached around a word, as in the German *ge-* + *-t*, and this is called a *[circumfix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumfix)*.

There are some more exotic types of affix described in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix).

I would note that these terms are usually used in linguistics for *morphemes*, and surrounding a word with punctuation is not usually considered circumfixation.

Comment: I don't think I would call that an _infix_, because that implies a grammatical or derivational morpheme, and almost certainly a bound morpheme.Examples are rare to non-existent in English, but French shows an infix in the interrogative of "il y a": "y a-t-il". Forms like _abso-fucking-lutely_ are referred to as _tmesis_.

Comment: @Colin, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive_infixation

Comment: Some programming languages have circumfix operators. You can think of the four bracketing types as such, actually.

Comment: @tchrist: the way that terms of art may have been picked up and used in other fields doesn't necessarily tell us anything about the meaning or use of the words in the original domain. A "statement" in a programming language has only a metaphorical relationship to a "statement" in language.

Comment: Portuguese has *mesoclitic* pronouns in its future and conditional tenses.  They come after the verb stem but before the inflection. And they are subject to contraction, too.